# building new data.table from the old one

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table DT with columns `k,v:  (k1, v1), (k2, v2), (k3, v3)...`

I would like to group values by key and then do something with them and produce a new data table (or frame) `(s1, t1), (s2, t2)...`.

Each grouped `(k, v1, ..vi)` set can be mapped to 0 or more rows in the destination data.table `dest`, which have totally different range of keys, not related to k.

I understand that I can write: `DT[, myfun(k,v), by=k]` but I am not sure how that helps me.

For example, assume that my function `myfun` needs to compute `s = prod(v1, ...vi)` and then 
to increase row `s` by `k`: `dest[s] += k`.

I am not sure how can I code this in R!

Answer (score 0):

You create an summarised version of DT:

```
DT1 <- DT[, prod(v), by=k]
```

and then use the values of this to increase `dest`, the $v now equals the *s* in your post and so identifies the rows to be incremented:

```
dest[DT1$v, "columnToBeIncreased"] = dest[DT1$v, "columnToBeIncreased"] +DT1$k
```

You say dest is a data.table, and you want to increase a row by a given amount.  If you want the whole row (ie all the columns in that row) to be increased, omit the "columnToBeIncreased" (remove even the quotes, but leave the preceeding comma) - otherwise set it to the the name of the column you want to be incremented.

Comment: That's almost what I need. What if my function needs to emit several rows. Say `(prod(v), k), (prod(v)+1, k^2)`. Is it possible to do in data.table?

Comment: If you want to **alter** several rows, then simply add another line `dest[DT1$v+1,] =dest[DT1$v+1,] + (DT1$k)^2`.  If by _emit_ you mean you're not incremending dest _in situ_ but generating an new modified subset then you can do `newDT = rbind(LHS1, LHS2)`  where the LHSs are the left-hand sides of the `dest=dest+DT` lines in the answer and in this comment

Comment: No, I meant by emitting phase something like this:
`DT = data.table(A=rep(1:5,5),B=21:45)
res = rep(0, 50)
DT[, { res[B] = res[B] + 1; res[B+1] = res[B+1] + 2;} , by=A]
`
The code in the curly braces does not change res for some reason.

Comment: So I think my previous comment covers that - use the first line of my code to generate the relevant summaries of v within groups of k - you can even do `DT[,list(p=prod(v), s=sum(v)), by=k]`  and then for every set of changes to res you need, have s separate `res[DT$p] <- res[DT$p] + DT[k]` assignment.  If this isn't it, please provide a full example including the values you'd expect as final output.

Comment: If you really want to assign external variables from within the DT grouping operation, you can replace `=` with `<<-`, so you have `{res[prod(B)] <<- res[prod(B)] + 1` for example.  I'm not sure what putting an non-scalar version of `B` in their is guaranteed to do in the presence of a grouping factor, so either drop the `by` or add a guaranteed scalar function (such as prod or sum or mean) around instances of B